# allow Special Characters in URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to allow special charecters in URL
my htaccess code is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^blog/?$ SocialNetwork/blog.php [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/(\d+)/?$ SocialNetwork/blog.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog.php/(\d+)/?$ SocialNetwork/blog.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog.php/(\d+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_[]]+)/?$ SocialNetwork/blog.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

it works for

`blog/1`
`blog/1/hii`
`blog/1yooo_title`

but does not work for

`blog/1/[hii-this is [] title`

Comment: `blog/1/[hii-this is [] title` is an invalid URL actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last rewrite rule, try escaping the square brackets. Also if you need to match spaces you need to include \s in there:

```
^blog.php/(\d+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_\[\]\s]+)/?$
```

Or perhaps consider the simpler which accepts anything in the title:

```
^blog.php/(\d+)/(.+)/?$
```

Another point is that you should not have spaces in your URLs. They should be escaped to "+" or %20. So depending on this your regex would change, except the last one I proposed should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can't use spaces in a URL. Ever.

Answer (score 0):

only alphanumerics, the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used unencoded within a URL.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt